# Why is this program not creating a core dump?

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault, malloc, free

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654754/what-really-happens-when-you-dont-free-after-malloc) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992924/importance-of-freeing-memory?lq=1), the operating system is freeing wathever you've malloced in your program as long as you close it, moreover in a simple program like mine it's not so important.

> Sure in very short running simple programs, failing to free memory
>   won't have a noticeable effect.   [jaredpar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar)

According to man :

> The malloc() function allocates **size** bytes [...]

So, I have used malloc to allocate an array of integer with **20 bytes** of memory (`sizeof int` is **4 bytes** on my system) :

```
array = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
```

Therefore I should be able to write just 5 integers (5 * 4 bytes = 20 bytes = 5 integers). Now this program here should create a core dump, but this is not the case, for some reason :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

        int *array = NULL, i = 0;

        array = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

        if(array == NULL)
        {
                printf("\nERROR : Out of memory.\n");
                return 1;
        }

        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                scanf("%d", &array[i]);

return 0;

}
```

This program lets me input 10 integers without the creation of a coredump...Instead using `free(array)` at the end of the program will correctly result in the creation of a core dump. Isn't that strange? Shouldn't both programs create a core dump? Why doesn't using free() doesn't create a core dump?
I know what a core dump is and how to avoid it, my question is purely curiosity as, for me, this is a strange behaviour.

Comment: Because *Undefined Behavior* is undefined. You can't expect a defined behavior from it. Also, use `if (array == NULL)` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [segfault with array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678793/segfault-with-array)

Comment: If the OS frees memory when the program is closed, why is it undefined? Should it give me a core dump as well? P.S = Fixed with NULL

Comment: The behaviour is undefined by the C standard, which means anything is allowed to happen.   One compiler/library may build the code with no problems, and another may simply give a crash.   One possible result is behaving in a way that make it seem like nothing is wrong.  Another possible result is behaving as if nothing is wrong, and then crashing at the next blue moon.

Comment: Then whoever says that using free() for simple program is useless is wrong, as using it will point out if you have done some error.

Comment: It will not always point out anything. You may create undefined behavior and have `free` finish without apparent problems.

Comment: @Claudio No, you are very confused about how this works.  There is no "*should* cause a core dump".  There is only "*could* cause a core dump".  If you have a memory error in your program, *anything* can happen.  It *may* cause a core dump, or it *may* cause strange behavior, or it *may* not be detectable at all.  All bets are off.  Similarly with `free`.  You cannot depend on `free` to catch your bugs for you.  If you have a memory error, `free` *may* detect it, or it *may* cause a core dump, or it *may* do nothing special at all.

Comment: @MartinJames My question is more related to the use of free() that will lead to a core dump than the segfault itself

Comment: Your call to `free` causes a core dump likely because you overwrite some of libc's data structures which control memory allocation, and which `free` relies on. You're just lucky that it caused immediate core dump, not just strange behavior.

Comment: Following @Ruslan comment, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work

Comment: @Ruslan Thank you, I kind of understeand now. So free() doesn't necessarly give segfault, also if this is the case for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't both programs create a core dump?

It *could*, but it doesn't *have to*.

Your program exercises *undefined behavior*, and the result of executing such program is undefined:

- it could exit successfully,
- it could abort,
- it could crash with a segmentation fault,
- it could melt your CPU,
- it could launch nuclear missiles.

That's *exactly* what undefined behavior means: anything could happen.

Your expectation that a *particular* thing would happen is incorrect.